# How to get CORS/CORB error message in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, cors, sentry

I'm trying to catch in JS and log to Sentry an error thrown when doing AJAX `GET` request to the API where `CORS` is disabled. I can't get the error message in jQuery `fail()` function nor in `$(document).on({ajaxError:...})`. The only content of my `xhr` object is `{"readyState":0,"withCredentials":true,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}` I see, however, the following messages in my console: Error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://***/' from origin 'https://***' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to reflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

thrown by my HTML file, and a warning

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://***/ with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

thrown by `raven.js`.
Is there any option to capture these messages in JS as they are seen in colsole?

I'd like to underline, that I don't want to get rid of CORS error (set `*`, etc). I just want to catch it.

Comment: Possible duplicate or maybe this should help you : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970475/get-all-javascript-errors-on-page-javascript-error-handling

Comment: @arielb, thanks for the answer, but this is for redirecting all console messages. I wonder if there is a chance to catch this one.

Comment: Not really sure but if anything can catch this it's this: https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/security-policy-reporting/

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721584/catching-an-access-control-allow-origin-error-in-javascript/42723074#42723074. The gist of it is, The details of errors for XHR and Fetch API requests are not exposed to frontend JavaScript, by design, for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you @sideshowbarker. I consider this question as answered.