# Fetching error gives more information on error in console than in catch method

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

How can you get more information regarding the type of error once a fetch goes wrong?

In the following example the URL is invalid on purpose.

```js
fetch('https://intended-incorrect-url')
  .then(res => res.json)
  .catch(err => {
  document.getElementById('fetchResult').innerHTML = err.message;
});
```

```html
<div id="fetchResult"></div>
```

In this example the error message is only: `Failed to fetch`. But if you inspect the console the error is `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Is it possible to get more information regarding the exact nature of why the fetch failed?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `debugger` in the catch section? Then you can play with _everything_ that `err` returns to find a more detailed description.

Comment: Yes have tried that. The error object, or better yet the [reason](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#Syntax) object only has a `.stack` or `.message` method for little information.

Comment: According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

Failing to get it is the only error you can get from a `fetch` call.

Also found this which is similar to your issue: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42723074/441757. While the browser itself will log a more-detailed error message to the console, you can’t access that message from your code. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118096#c5: *“The details of errors of XHR and Fetch API are not exposed to JavaScript for security reasons.”*